# How should I straighten my bent baby Euclyptus Tree?

Tags: trees

I purchased a small Rainbow Euclyptus tree off Ebay about 1.5 months ago. It arrived healthy and looks to be doing well.  Though I'm concerned as it has a really crooked part of the trunk just at the base.  Knowing how huge this tree will become...should I be concerned? How should I go about straightening it?  I'm thinking either:

1. Put in some stakes and rope to slowly unbend the trunk.
2. Or Simply dig a deeper hole and bury that bent portion underground.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave it alone.  That bend will always be there but your tree will always head for the sun.  Not to worry.  The bend will become less obvious as the diameter of your trunk gets larger with age.  To stake your tree will make your trunk weaker and delay root growth for support.  Staking is just like putting a cast on your arm or leg.  Take that cast off and guess what?  You've got a vastly weakened arm, leg or trunk and root system.

Something vastly more important that you probably do not notice is that mulch up against your tree.  THAT WILL KILL your tree eventually.  Pull the mulch back to allow that bark to dry.  Only ONLY the roots should be beneath the soil, never any of the woody stem!

Answer (score 2):

1. No 2. No

Many eucalypts in the wild look like yours. The tree will naturally straighten up to a point and, if it requires additional strength, it will naturally buttress its trunk. I would stake the tree to stop it blowing over in a strong wind but otherwise would leave the tree to its own devices.